# lists as argument and method calls

Tags: python, list, function, class

Hoping someone can help. I mainly work in Java and have an assignment that I have to do in Python and I know next to nothing about it.

I have a CSV file which I'm reading in and have managed to create a list or lists of each item. Each line represents a thingID, time of request, time requested, time needed to fill. I need to place these into a priority queue, run them through and print results. Though I haven't gotten farther than what is shown below as I clearly have no idea how functions work. The whole self and `__init__` stuff has me confused, along with everything else that this language requires to operate.

```
def main():
    with open('things.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        index = 0
        for row in reader:
            print(row)

main()
```

This gives me a list of arrays like so:

```
['Thing1', '0', '1', '4']
['Thing2', '1', '1', '3']
```

I have another Things.py (am not supposed to have multiple classes in a single .py) in which I have:

```
class Things(object):
    def __init___(self, row, thingInfo):
        self.row = row
        self.thingInfo = thingInfo
```

I tried creating another `def` below the `__init__` but I can't do anything.
I'm trying to separate out the different parts of the list object so I can then operate on the various parts of it like ID, time requested, etc., but have no idea how to do this. I've tried various things but get Attribute Error of Type Error. I'm at a total loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just need a few steps in the right direction as I've completely hit a wall.

Comment: Methods in Java don't operate any different than Java. The init method doesn't act much different than Java class constructors. It's not very clear what you are trying to do with each row of the CSV

Comment: And Python doesn't care if you have multiple classes per script... Is your question how to import the Things class?

Comment: If you don't know anything about Python, your first step should be learning it via a course or tutorial. SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: " I've tried various things but get Attribute Error of Type Error. " you could turn that into a specific programming question, instead of this very general "I need help" question.

Comment: Sorry if my question was too general. I tried to be as specific as I could. I even searched the other questions surrounding the attribute error but couldn't make sense of it. I know full well that this is not a tutorial service, but this is for an assignment and was not given time to learn it as one should. I was more or less looking for a way to unpack which someone generously helped me with, so now I can move on to the next step and hopefully figure the rest out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List unpacking may be what your want:

```
class Things(object):
    def doSomething(self):
        thing_id, time_of_request, time_requested, time_needed_to_fill = self.row
        # do whatever u want with the above variables
```

Comment: Thank you. This was super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this template helps:

```
class Things(object):

    def __init___(self, row, thingInfo):
        self.row = row
        self.thingInfo = thingInfo

    def doSomething(self, arg1, arg2): # beware the `self`
        for x in self.row:
            # do something with x, like:
            print(x)

# here is where you use Things
thing = Things([1, 2, 3], 'info')
thing.doSomething(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly separate out the different parts of the list object passed to `Things.__init__()` by indexing them like this (same as in Java ):

```
class Things(object):
    def __init___(self, row, thingInfo):
        self.row = row
        self.id = thingInfo[0]
        self.time_requested = thingInfo[1]
        self.another_thing = thingInfo[2]
        # etc ...
```